# How to write a method that would automatically take data value based on the input variable name

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON object like this :

```
 data = { a1 : 'value',
          a2 : 'value2',
          a3 : 'value3' }
```

And I have a method like this in javascript selenium

```
  class abc {

        var a1 =  "xpath"
        var a2 =  "xpath"
        var a3 = "xpath"

        public filldata (data) {
            this.a1.value(data.a1)
            this.a2.value(data.a2)
            this.a3.value(data.a3)
        }

  }
```

Is it possible to write some method that would automatically assign `data` value based on the `this.var` value?

Comment: Try looking for `Object.assign()` or `for...in` loop

Comment: Do you need to assign all keys from `data` object in the `this` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
data = {
  a1: 'value1',
  a2: 'value2',
  a3: 'value3',
}

class ABC {
  public fillData(data) {
    Object.assign(this, data);

    console.log(this); // will return: { a1: 'value1', a2: 'value2', a3: 'value3' }
  }
}

ABC.fillData(data);
```